# SQL Tuning advisor doesn't show tips for exec sp_executesql

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I have some problems while I try to find out with SQL Server Tuning Advisor what may be improved within my:

```
exec sp_executesql '(dynamic-sql)', (parameter types), (parameter values)
```

Tuning advisour is thinking for a while and have no recommendations. Meanwhile when I ask him to think about:

query with the same parameter values (raw sql code) - I have good recommendations what indexes should I create.

So I wonder:

1. Does SQL Server Tuning Advisor may optimize exec sp_executesql statements ?

2a. If "yes" then shall I use raw sql code instead of sp_executesql because this raw code has good recommendations?

2b. If "no" then will optimizations for raw sql code improve sp_executesql statement after all ?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I believe `sp_executesql` will eventually build your SQL and execute it independently, so you will see it on another entry (it's own), outside `sp_executesql`.

Comment: Perhaps the answer of EzLo is correct, DTA  can see dynamic SQL as an independent execution context...

Comment: Mm, I think @Ezlo is on the mark as well. Like I made comment in my (now deleted) answer, I think it might be helpful to see a dynamic sql statement that you aren't seeing. If you're using **properly** parametrised dynamic SQL, then those queries *will* be stored in the query plan cache for reuse; with the advisor checks. On the other hand, if you aren't, then those queries will be lost quickly and unlikely to be checked. perhaps the real problem is that the OP's dynamic statements are using parameter injection, rather than passing their values.

Comment: Why don'y you execute it with set statisctics xml on? All index recommendations will be shown in the plan